# how to convert javascript variable to php variable in the same file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have file named test6.php having javascript variable i need to convert this variable to php variable but when i run it give me an e error (PHP Notice:  Undefined index: variable in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test6.php on line 14)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var variableToSend = 'foo';
    $.post('test6.php', {variable: variableToSend});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$x = $_POST['variable'];
echo $x;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

note that i have only one file (test6.php) containing javascript code and php code and i am trying to convert javascript variable to php variable in the same file and i need to use post not get or submit form

Comment: Do you realize that the JavaScript code runs after the PHP code?

Comment: yes i know , ok what is the simplest way to do that with one file

Answer (score 0):

#### Why  error

you should know the processing of a php file rendering from the server to the client , it is :

```
1. client request the page
2. PHP parser (in server) -> php 2 HTML -> send to client
2. web browser load HTML 
3. JavaScript running ~
```

so you can't get variable of "variable" when you run your php file . Becuase Js has not been running ~ .  you should print the value of php echo at JS after ajax .

how about change the JQuery code

```
$.post('test6.php', {variable: variableToSend});
```

to

```
$.post('test6.php', {variable: variableToSend} , 
        function(returnValue){
             console.log(returnValue) ; 
        });
```

I think it will be ok , but i am sorry i can't test it ~

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it is set before you output it

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['variable']) ) {
        $x = $_POST['variable'];
        echo $x;
    }
?>
```

But I do not think this is what you actually want. The Ajax call is not going to update the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Bring the php section to the top and use isset($_POST['variable']) to check if the variable exist or not.

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['variable']) ){
    $x = $_POST['variable'];
    echo $x;
    return;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var variableToSend = 'foo';
    $.post('test6.php', {variable: variableToSend});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```